# Error: remoteAddress not set - jreactive-8583

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Our server is running fine and below is very basic version of our code:

```
MessageFactory<IsoMessage> messageFactory = ConfigParser.createDefault();
Iso8583Client<IsoMessage> client = new Iso8583Client< (socketAddress,ClientConfiguration.getDefault(),messageFactory);
client.addMessageListener(new IsoMessageListener<IsoMessage>() {

        @Override
    public boolean applies(IsoMessage arg0) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, IsoMessage arg1) {

        return false;
    }
});
client.getConfiguration().setReplyOnError(true);

client.init();
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 8080);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("Problem in client Connection");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting following error, please help:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: remoteAddress not set
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:116)
at com.github.kpavlov.jreactive8583.client.Iso8583Client.connectAsync(Iso8583Client.java:88)
at com.github.kpavlov.jreactive8583.client.Iso8583Client.connect(Iso8583Client.java:48)
at com.github.kpavlov.jreactive8583.client.Iso8583Client.connect(Iso8583Client.java:75)
at com.github.kpavlov.jreactive8583.client.Iso8583Client.connect(Iso8583Client.java:63)
at com.tushar.jreactive8583.demo_iso8385.AppClient.main(AppClient.java:62)**

Comment: did u solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Iso8583Client<IsoMessage> client = new Iso8583Client<>(messageFactory);
```

With

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080);
Iso8583Client<IsoMessage> client = new Iso8583Client<>(socketAddress, messageFactory);
```

Comment: You should explain what your code improves, and why this should work

Comment: Old method has marked as deprecated. so, its code from examples.